# The end-symbol isn't shown at the correct place in bower

Tags: javascript, bower

When I use `<option>`, if I use any symbol at the end of the text, I get the symbol at the fist place in bower.

For example:

```html
<select>
  <option>test(that's test)</option>
</select>
```

Then I can only get `(test(that's test`. What's going on?

How can I fix this?

Comment: the last "symbol" in the example is a `)` ... but you say the first "symbol" output is `(` ... `(` !== `)` ... something else is going on

Comment: Yeah, I know. That happens in my case.